# Как осуществить связь между двумя виртуальными машинами запущенными на одном хосте, с сохранением доступа в интернет и подключения по SSH?

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, virtualbox

Запущены две виртуальные машины на одном хосте, данные машины имеют статические ip адреса:
vm1- 192.168.100.10/16, vm2- 172.24.116.8/12. Между ними нужно осуществить передачу данных, также у каждой vm должен быть доступ в интернет и возможность подключения по SSH  с хоста.

Посмотрел доступные варианты, такие как : NAT, Briget Network и тд. Но не понимаю, какой вариант стоит использовать, да и не могу представить картину, как это реализовать.

Использую VirtualBox с Ubuntu 20.04, хост на Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему использованием: Internal Network, объедив данные адаптеры в одну внутреннюю виртуальную сеть.

Answer (score 1):

Для связи между двумя виртуальными машинами запущенными на одном хосте, с сохранением доступа в интернет и подключения по SSH. Нужно выбрать сетевой мост, и настроить сетевой адаптер так, чтобы он получал сетевые настройки от DHCP локальной сети.

Comment: Сетевой адаптер, тот, который виртуальный? Насколько я понимаю.

Comment: Конечно виртуальный